# use DES-EDE3 encryption in node js using crypto

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I need to encrypt a string using DES-EDE3 algorithm and a key. The working code for that in php is like this:

```
$encrypted = OpenSSL_encrypt($plain, "DES-EDE3", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```

but I want it for node js project. So I rewrote this code like so:

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("des-ede3", "the key", null);
let encryptedData = cipher.update("the data", "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
let decodedData= Buffer.from(encryptedData , "base64").toString(); //cause i want it raw
```

But it gives me the `invalid key length` error. I tried other ways like hashing the key using md5 but in that case it does not give me the same string that the php code does.

Comment: Can you post some example key that is similar in format but different from your actual key?

Comment: @ArtjomB. the key is something like this: `�lS7�Q��%7��n�q��ݦ�G�` which is a base64 decoded of a string like this: `9GxTN6pRqOGNJTfDwG4Q6HGD5d2m6keR` given to me from an api. The data itself is a combination of price and payment gateway token and factor number seperated using `;` character.

Comment: The reason why @Artjom B. asked for the key is that OpenSsl sometimes uses a key derivation method and other times it brings a too short (or too long) key to the right length. If we can't see the (**sample**) key we can't realy help you with your problem. If you want to get a good and reliable answer kindly edit your question and post a minimal running example of your PHP encryption code (simplify the plaintext, use a key that has the same length as the real one and get the ciphertext as hexstring or base64 encoded output. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Base64 encoded key `9GxTN6pRqOGNJTfDwG4Q6HGD5d2m6keR` corresponds Base64 decoded to a 24 bytes key and thus a key that [Triple-DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) expects. Triple-DES is based on DES and corresponds to three executions of DES (encryption/decryption/encryption), using one of the keys for each execution.

The posted PHP code returns the following result for the plaintext *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog* and the posted key:

```
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'des-ede3', base64_decode('9GxTN6pRqOGNJTfDwG4Q6HGD5d2m6keR'), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
print(base64_encode($encrypted)); // +sEO1gYe1Jk1+cslkLHDlSPwEOeFUBqKS7giqBnishiAcC9YfPxYiIJssg2Xu+e6
```

To display the data a suitable encoding is required, e.g. Base64. Alternatively instead of the explicit Base64 encoding with `base64_encode` the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag could be omitted (i.e. `0` could be used), which implicitly Base64 encodes.

The NodeJS code provides the same result with the following changes:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("des-ede3", Buffer.from('9GxTN6pRqOGNJTfDwG4Q6HGD5d2m6keR','base64'), null);
let encryptedData = cipher.update("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
//let decodedData= Buffer.from(encryptedData , "base64").toString(); //cause i want it raw
console.log(encryptedData); // +sEO1gYe1Jk1+cslkLHDlSPwEOeFUBqKS7giqBnishiAcC9YfPxYiIJssg2Xu+e6
```

Note that the line `let decodedData=...` has been commented out, because it UTF8-decodes and thus *corrupts* the ciphertext.

If you want to have raw data, this would be closest to data in a buffer:

```
let encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "utf8"), cipher.final()]);
console.log(encryptedData.toString('base64')); // +sEO1gYe1Jk1+cslkLHDlSPwEOeFUBqKS7giqBnishiAcC9YfPxYiIJssg2Xu+e6
```

which again are Base64 encoded here for output.

`des-ede3` (equivalent to `des-ede3-ecb`) denotes Triple-DES in ECB mode. Triple-DES is an outdated cipher that should be replaced by e.g. the higher performant AES. Also note, that the [ECB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946) mode is generally insecure. Better choices are CBC or authenticated encryption using GCM mode.